# 2 factor authentication in Grails

Tags: grails, groovy

I want a way to implement 2 factor authentication. When the user enters their username and password it moves them to another page where they are granted a temporary Role and then they are asked to enter a security token which will be sent to them via email. [authtoken image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6szT.png)

[login image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3YHI.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. We can help you better if you show us your code. What have you tried so far? And further reading: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I have been there and I discovered that its pretty easy to implement this mostly in custom code if you are in conventional old school web app. I think there is something in spring that allows you to do this, but depending on your application it might be just so much easier to do this by yourself and not even that difficult.

One way is to create grails filter that covers all routes that are affected by this. For example all except login page and the second page after that. This filter will check the temp role and if found, it will redirect to the second auth page. Otherwise it lets the request pass. Could be something like this:

```
twoFactorCheck(controller: '*', controllerExclude: 'privacyPolicy|login|logout|2factor', action: '*') {

    before = {

        if (process2factorAuthNeed()) {
            return true;
        }

        redirect(controller: "2factor", action: "index");
        return false;

    }
}
```

Then another thing you need is an implementation of custom UserDetailsService where you can capture the first normal authentication and set the temp role for the user. This is covered here: https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/2.0.x/guide/userDetailsService.html if you are on grails 2.* but your spring security plugins version user guide will have this entry as well.

Comment: Thank you very much I will look into it. I have been trying to understand how to implement the filter but I keep getting to wrong somehow